# Call outlook macro from Autohotkey

Tags: automation, outlook, autohotkey

I have several outlook macros that I call from AHK through keyboard shortcuts linked to the quick access bar.
This is unreliable and difficult to maintain.
Is there any way to call the macro directly from the AHK shortcut, I have looked as COM objects and DLL functions but none of the solutions seem applicable.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is absolutely a way. I used to do this with excel/outlook all the time but all of MS Office works. You can use [ComObjActive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/ComObjActive.htm) in AHK to send VBA-related commands. You can pull off more than macros too, its really cool. But for your needs its simple enough to call on a macro by name.

```
Outlook := ComObjActive("Outlook.Application")
Outlook.Run("Macro1") ;kick-off macro by name
Outlook.quit
```